# Symmetric array check, explanation needed

Tags: java, arrays

I have a piece of code that checks if an array is symmetric or not. But I don't understand exactly what is going on:

```java
int a[] =  {3, 5, 7, 5, 3}; 
boolean symm = true;

for (int i = 0; i < a.length / 2; i++) {
    if (a[i] != a[a.length -i -1]) {
        symm = false;
        break;
    }
}

if(symm)
    System.out.println("The array is symmetrical.");
else
    System.out.println("The array is not symmetrical.");
```

My questions are:

- How come `-i` is a part of the expression `a[a.length -i -1])`, is it simply because I'm checking the array from both sides?
- How come I have to use `-1` in the expression `a[a.length -i -1])`?

Comment: What do you mean by "keep track of the position of the elements in the array"?

Comment: `-i-1` is just to manage the 0 based indexing. This goes as first - last, second - second last, third - third last etc.

Comment: debug your program using a debugger or use simple [pen-and-paper tracing](https://sites.google.com/site/usfcomputerscience/tracing-1a) to see what's going on

Comment: FWIW 3 years later you can set symm in one line with `symm = a == a[::-1]` for short arrays. For longer ones, `half = round(len(a)/2)` followed by `symm = a[: half] == a[-1: half+1: -1]`, with the latter being more efficient as it only compares half the array with the other half.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are checking the array "from both ends".

The solution runs through the first half of the array, and checks each value against the value at the index from the other side of the array, that is the equal distance from the end, as the first index is from the beginning.

The `-i` is to index into the array "from the other end", as far into it as you are from the beginning of the array. And the `-1` is needed, because the index of the array starts at `0` (base 0, meaning that the index of the first item is 0 and not 1, so with an array of 5 elements, you will have indexes 0 through 4, and a length of 5. If you want to use the length to index into the array, you will often subtract 1 to get the index of the last element of the array)

Because the interger division `/ 2` will truncate the remainder, you will only traverse index 0 and 1 in the array, and compare those to index 4 and 3 respectively.

Here's an overview of the two iterations, with the value of `i` and the value of the calculated index that is compared against:

**First iteration**

```
[ 3 ] [ 5 ] [ 7 ] [ 5 ] [ 3 ]
  ^                       ^
  i = 0                   length - i - 1 = 4
                          5 - 0 - 1 = 4
```

**Second iteration:**

```
[ 3 ] [ 5 ] [ 7 ] [ 5 ] [ 3 ]
        ^           ^
        i = 1       length - i - 1 = 3
                    5 - 1 - 1 = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Fill in the columns.  This is a great way to see what is going on.  And especially helpful to figure out how one might approach a solution prior to coding it.

`a.length` = 5

```
+------+---+------+--------------+-----------------+
| step | i | a[i] | a.length-i-1 | a[a.length-i-1] |
+------+---+------+--------------+-----------------+
| 1    |   |      |              |                 |
+------+---+------+--------------+-----------------+
| 2    |   |      |              |                 |
+------+---+------+--------------+-----------------+
| 3    |   |      |              |                 |
+------+---+------+--------------+-----------------+
| 4    |   |      |              |                 |
+------+---+------+--------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: I actually tried doing something like this earlier on another example. I'll give it a shot on this one as well.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing here is checking the first and last, second and second last, .. elements of an array. Suppose you have an `array.length = 5`. The index will go from 0 to 4 i.e, `arr.length(5) - 1`.

> **The next question is why -i ?**

You'll be checking `a[0]` with `a[4]`, `a[1]` with `[3]`. When you have `i = 0`, `arr.length - i -1` i.e, 5 -0 -1 will give you `a[4]`. Similarly, when you have `i=1`, `arr.length -i -1` will give you 5 -1 -1 i.e, `a[3]`.